# A More Direct Proof Please of a Theorem of the Incomplete Gamma Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, gamma-function

I could not find a tag for *incomplete gamma function*, so I've just used the *gamma function* one.

A rather curious fact about the normalised incomplete gamma function$${1\over n!}\operatorname{\Gamma}(n,\mu)=\int_\mu^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x}dx$$ (or is that the *complementary* normalised incomplete gamma function?) is that it is equal to the *hypervolume cut out* by the hypersurface (a *hyperhyperbola*, maybe!) $$\prod_{k=1}^n x_k=e^{-\mu}$$ (the $x_k$ being coordinates in $n$-dimensional space) of the positive unit *hyperbox* with a corner at the origin, bounden by all the planes $x_j=0$ & $x_j=1$. (So it doesn't matter very much whether  it's the IGF or the *complementary* IGF that is under consideration, as the *other* function is just the hypervolume in the *other* part of the box.

I know a rather gross proof of this that consists in integrating the whole of the *present* function's representation as such a hypervolume along the *new* axis to get the next function up in the series of increasing $n$: the general case of this can without *tremendous* difficulty be 'abstracted' from the first two or three by broaching *yet another* curious theorem of binomial coefficients; but I am *not* much enamoured of the idea of setting it out, and I suppose few of you are strongly desirous of seeing it.

But the question is - does anyone know a *slick proof* of the theorem that is the chief subject of this post?  - by which I mean a proof that proceeds along somekind of *shortcut* or 'wormhole'  through the space of general function-theory, without recourse to just taking the thing apart & reconstructing it cog-by-cog, as in my method of proof ... but I think the meaning of *slick proof* is well-enough known amongst us! I feel that there *ought to be* and *probably is* such a proof - my intuition just cannot rest in the idea that there *isn't* one.

Comment: Change of variable $y_k = \log(x_k)$ ?

Comment: So what would by the volume enclosed in _that_ space? It would be just a _hyperplane_ across the _hypercorner_, I think, wouldn't it. The region would have a simpler shape ... but then to recover the original hypervolume there would have to be a _scaling_ that varies from point-to-point within the area, that would have to be _built-into_ the integral. Unfortunately, I don't think there's any elementary relation between exponential of integral &  integral of exponential (of function): I was wondering about that when I failed to find out what integral of gamma function is, but got one for lnΓ.

Comment: @reuns -- Maybe that scaling I mentioned wouldn't be too bad: coz if x_k=e^-y_k, then Π{k=1 to n}dx_j=-Π{k=1 to n}e^y_k.dy_k, so the function _to be integrated_ over the hypervolume is Π{k=1 to n}e^y_k ... but I'm having difficulty transforming _the boundaries_, as in the "x" formulation it's the part of the _hyperbox_ made by the planes x_k=0 & x_k=l (need to fix this in the question) cut off by the hyperhyperbola Πx=e^-μ: but in the "y" formulation the hyperhyperbola translates to the plane Σy=μ; but because y is from 0 to ∞, how does _the box_ transform!?

Comment: Oh right! I think I've got it now! I see what I was missing before! I think you're right actually. ¶ I'll see what these other comments say. I'll bet they're saying what you said ... & I'll bet you won't believe that I hadn't seen them when I wrote this!

Comment: @reuns I've made another comment above this one, but I forgot to put an "@" @ the beginning of it (hahaha! see what I did there!?). I think the _fog_ has cleared, now! ... or _is clearing_. Those comments though, that I'd gotten notification of, & expected to be admonishments apprising me of how _slow_ I am - they _were actually_ about something completely different. ¶ Thankyou for your contribution!